# Iterating an array of numbers using "for of loop"

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate the array below:

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,0,11]

for(let value of a)
{
    console.log(a[value-1])
}
```

I got the output as below. 
I'm unable to find why is 0 and 11 are printed as undefined.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation of for...of loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). With a for...of loops, the iterator variable is bound to the object, not the index number.

Comment: Are you sure you want the values at the indexes of a? If so, you're referring to non-existent indexes in a, specifically index -1 and 10

Comment: i actually wanted to iterate the values of 'a' but got confused. Now i got the clarity that i have to print the "value" not a[value]. Anyways thanks for the comment Robert Stiffler and  Chris Ochsenreither

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may be a simple misunderstanding of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

In each iteration, you're trying to access the item at index `a[value-1]`. Your first `undefined` comes from the value `0`, where you're attempting to access `a[0-1]`, or `a[-1]`. The second comes from value `11`, where you are trying to access `a[11-1]`, or `a[10]`.

Your array has no item at index `-1` nor index `10`, thus they are both `undefined`.

I've added some logging to your code to aid the explanation above:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 11]
for (let value of a) {
  console.log(`value is ${value}`);
  console.log(`Getting item at a[${value-1}]`);
  console.log(`Item is ${a[value - 1]}`);
  console.log(`-----`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```